# ASP.Net Web Api initial requests are taking too long

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Initial requests are taking 3-5 seconds, subsequent calls takes < 500 milliseconds. Service makes a light weight stored proc call and there is no latency found when we profile it.
This service does not hit very frequently and Idle Time-out of the Process model is 20 minutes (default). We tried to hit it every 19 minutes but no change.

Service running under IIS 7.5 with .Net framework 4.5

Comment: Is there anything else running on the server?

Comment: No. Just this service.

Comment: Did you try something like [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/) to profile the service?

Comment: Glimpse is like ELMAH ?

Answer (score 2):

The first request for an ASP.NET website always takes some time because the code needs to be compiled. You can install a module for IIS that automatically makes that initial request so you don't get that slowdown yourself.

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-initialization

Comment: How could a request before the time out expires be considered a "first request"? :)